# Max score to reach end of array with step length

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Assume an array and we start from element at index 0. We want to go from 0 index to last index of the array by taking steps of at max length K.

For example, suppose an array is [10,2,-10,5,20] and K is 2, which means maximum step length is 2 (We can assume K is always possible and less than length of array).
Now as we start from index 0, our score currently is 10 and then we can either go to 2 or can go to -10. Suppose we go to 2 from here so total score becomes 10+2=12. Now from 2 we can go to -10 or 5 so you go to 5 making score 12+5=17. From here you directly go to last index as you have no way other than that, hence total score is 17+20=37.

For given array of length N and an integer K we need to find maximum score we can get.
I thought of a solution, to divide it into sub problems by deciding weather to go at index i or not and recursively call the remaining array. But I sense some dynamic programming out of this problem.

How can this be solved for given array of size N and integer K.

Constraint : 1<=N<=100000 and 1<=K<=N

Comment: should be easy to think of a dynamic programming solution that runs in O(n*k), would that complexity suffice?

Comment: @juvian No, I am thinking of something lesser than O(n*k). Assume N can go to 100000 and K is lesser than N, but in worst case can go upto 100000.

Comment: Any information on possible values of the array or maximum sum that can be the result?

Comment: @juvian Array element absolute value can range between 0 to 100000.

Comment: As long as there is a positive element in the next k indexes, it is always optimal to go to it. So the only problem is when you have at least k negative values in a row

Comment: @juvian Agreed. Also problem will be if you have two positive elements, and choosing one ends up choosing a bigger negative number as next step.

Comment: You are right. Is there are online link for this problem?

Comment: @juvian Nope. I don't remember exact problem source. Was asked by one my friend and I was trying for a while.

Comment: "If you have two positive elements, and choosing one ends up choosing a bigger negative number as next step". This can´t happen, if there are two positive elements, you will choose both.

Comment: @juvian Oh yeah. Because step length is at max K and we don't have constraint on number of steps. So you are correct, problem is when you have at least k negative values in a row.

Comment: I would try to code that greedy solution for when there are no k negative values in a row, and when there are, use the standard dynamic programming approach to try to maximize the sum in that range of negative values.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta  Does O(n*logk) is enough?

Answer (score 2):

Came up with a `O(n*k)` solution.
Main function call would be findMax(A,N,K,0).

```
MAX = new Array();
MAX[i] = null. For 0<=i<N
```

null denoting the particular element has not been filled.

```
procedure findMax(A,N,K,i)
 {
  if (MAX[i]!=null)
   return MAX[i];
  else if (i==N-1)
   MAX[i]=A[i];
  else
   {
    MAX[i]=A[i]+findMax(A,N,K,i+1);

    for (j=2; j<=K&&(i+j)<N; ++j)
     if (A[i]+findMax(A,N,K,i+j)>MAX[i])
      MAX[i]=A[i]+findMax(A,N,K,i+j);
   }

  return MAX[i];
 }
```

The problem has optimal sub-structure property. To calculate optimal solution, all sub-problems need to be computed. So at a quick glance, I guess the time complexity wont go below `O(n*k)`.

Comment: I think recompute each time can be avoided. Thinking how to do that.

Comment: I dont think re-computations can be avoided. This problem is in a sense similar to the matrix chain multiplication problem. Some optimisations can be made at places but the overall point cannot be avoided. You cannot decide the optimal solution without trying every possible solution.

Comment: For any given i 0<=i<N MAX[i] = (largest element in the range A[i .. i+K]) + MAX[ i + (index of largest element in A[i .. i+K]) ].

Comment: I think there is small fault in this algorithm, for input say with three elements [10,-20,-5] and max step length of 2 it will give 10 and not  10-5=5

Comment: Is it necessary for us to pick atleast one number between the range A[i .. i+K]? I did not take that into account. Anyway, I think there's a `O(n)` solution possible. Im thinking about it.

Comment: Another example : 5 elements 
[100,-70,-90,-80,100] and max step length of 3 answer should be 100-70+100=130 but here it will give 100.

Comment: Yes it is necessary for us to pick atleast one number between the range A[i .. i+K]

Comment: Yeah I've taken that into account and modified my answer. Also it seems there's no general `O(n)` solution. I just bamboozled myself :D

Comment: So just replace the content of the for loop with finding local max and sum it with A[i] and set in Max[i]

Comment: Not exactly. Its about finding the index `j` that would maximize `A[i] + findMax(A,N,K,i+j)`.

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction  Missing some boundary base case as am getting Runtime Exception. Input is too huge to share haha. :)

Comment: Well then, type in the function code and stack trace.

Comment: I know - find that local max. And by the way for dynamic programing start from the end and walk backward - it can be done in O(n)

Comment: @DavidWinder Can you elaborate ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DavidWinder I dont think thats possible. Let k=3. A = [9998899,-200000,100,-100,-2000,-3000,-40000,-500000,3,9]. You would still need to scan K elements a.k.a A[i-K ... i-1] for each `i` value while walking backwards. That makes it `O(n*k)`.

Comment: @GauravGupta Try making the vector <long long>?

Comment: In your answer, you traverse the array right to left. So the indices should be subtracted, not added I guess?

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction Edit my answer to O(n*log k)

Answer (score 1):

Try to walk backward this way you can achieve that in **O(n*logk)**.

If the array was on size 1 the the max was that element. Consider you in the i-element - you can take him or one of the next K element -> choose the one that maximize your final result.

Consider the following pseudo code:

Base on @RandomPerfectHashFunction answer with some change

Consider Max as our answer array and tree as AVL Tree( self balancing binary search Tree)

```
findMaxStartingFromIndex(A,N,K,i, Max, Tree)
    if Max[i] != null
        return Max[i]
    max = Tree.Max // log k - just go down all the way to the right 
    if (i + k > N) // less then k element to end of array
        max = max(max,0) // take the maximum only if he positive 
    Max[i] = A[i] + max
    Tree.add(Max[i])
    if (i + k < N)
        Tree.remove(Max[i+k]) // remove the element from tree because it is out of the rolling-window of k elements
    return Max[i]
```

In Main:

```
Init Max array at size N
Init Tree as empty AVL tree
Max[N-1] = A[N-1]
Tree.add(MAX[N-1])
for (i = N-2; i >= 0 ; i--)
    findMaxStartingFromIndex(A,N,K,i, Nax, Tree)
```

When all done look for the max in the first k element of the **Max** array (no always choosing the first element is the best option)

Adding finding and removing element to binary search tree is log n -> in our case tree will hold only k element -> we achieve O(n*logk) complexity

Comment: I am not sure if I follow, but what would your algorithm do for k = 3 and [-1, -2, -3, -100, -100, 1]? The solution should be go to -3 and then to 1, even if the best in range (-1, -3) is -1.

Comment: In that case the the Max array will be set as: [-3,-4,-2,0,0,1] -> now looking at the first k=3 element and choose -2 as the max -> -2 represent -3 + 1 as you point out is truly the best answer

Comment: How can that be max array if Max[i] = A[i] + max will be -100 + max when i = N - 2 and N - 3?

Comment: Edited - just need to check for negative after adding the A[i]. Thanks

Comment: With k = 3 and [1, -100, -100, -3, -2, -1] max array would be [1,-100,-100,0,0,-1] and would give wrong answer. I think it should be: max = max(max,A[i])

Comment: I was mis-calculating the Max array - I return the code as it was before. Max array should be [-3,-4,-2,-99,-99,1]

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in `O(n) time and memory`

basically: go from back from i = n-1 to 0 and you have to know somehow what is the best index from i+1 up to i+k right? Then best answer for i would be to jump on the best index in range [i+1, i+k]

To get that information you can create some sort of queue (but you need to be able to perform pop from both sides in c++ you can use dequeue).
In that queue you keep two informations: (time, value), where time is the time at which you pushed element and value is best sum you can get if you start from element.

Now when you are in index i: first pop until current time (lest name it t) minus queue.top.time is > k: `while( t-que.top.time > k) que.pop`

Then you can take `que.top.value + array[i]` and that is the best value you can get from index i.

Last part to do is updating queue. You create new element  `e = (t,  que.top.value + array[i])` and take que.back (instead of que.top) and perform

```
while (que.back.value <= e.value) que.pop_back
```

Then you can push back

```
que.push_back(e)
```

and increase t++

This works because, when your new element has better value then elements inserted on the que in the past its better to keep this element instead, because you will be able to use it longer.

Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: I am not sure if I follow, but what would your algorithm do for  k = 3 and [-1, -2, -3, -100, -100, 1]? The solution should be go to -3 and then to 1, even if the best in range (-1, -3) is -1.

Comment: @Kasper Notice that your algorithm yield o(n*k) because of the while loop of popping element from queue in every index i (1-n)

Comment: David, no it doesn’t. It works in O(n), because you pop and insert each element at most once :). So when you count all pops and pushes you will end up with number like 2*n or so, but it’s still O(n)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `O(n)`. I'm assuming you're already familiar with the basic DP algorithm, which runs in `O(nk)`. We have `dp[i] = value[i] + (max(dp[j]) for i - k < j < i)`. The `k` factor in the complexity comes from finding the minimum of the last `k` values in our DP array, which we can optimize to `O(1)`.

One optimization might be to maintain a binary search tree containing the last `k` values, which would make an `O(n log k)` solution. But we can do better by using a double-ended queue instead of a binary search tree.

We maintain a deque containing the candidates for the maximum of the last `k` elements. Before we push the current `dp` value into the back of the deque, we pop off the value at the back if it is less than or equal to the current value. Because the current value is both better (or at least as good) than the value in the back and will be in the deque for longer, the value at the back will never be the maximum in the deque and can be discarded. We repeat this until the value at the back is no longer less than or equal to the current value.

We can then pop off the front value if its index is less than the current index minus `k`.

The way we popped off numbers from the back makes our queue always decreasing, so the maximum value is at the front.

Note that even though the loop popping off the values at the back might run as much as `n - 1` times in an iteration of the main loop, the total complexity is still `O(n)` because each element in the DP array popped off at most once.

Answer (score 1):

this can be solved with dynamic programming. dp[i] means the maximum scores we can collect from nums[0] to nums[i]. Transition is dp[i] = max(dp[i-1], dp[i-2],...,dp[i-k])+nums[i]. Time complexity is O(nk).

Answer (score 0):

A greedy solution. You might find it is easier to understand.

```
class Solution {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Init
  int[]path= {10,2,-10,5,20};
  int maxStep=2;
  int max=path[0];
  if(path.length==0)System.out.println(0);
  for(int i=0;i<path.length-1;) {
   int index=0,temp=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   //for each step, choose the step that has max value
   for(int j=1;(j<=maxStep)&&(i+j<=path.length-1);j++) {
      if(i+j>path.length-1)break;
      if(path[i+j]>temp) {
      temp=path[i+j];
      index=j;
    }
   }
   //change the index and the max value
   i+=index;max+=temp;
  }
  System.out.println(max);
 }
}
```

Comment: Only 3 test cases are passing

Answer (score 0):

This was asked today in my interview .Two of the answers here posted best approach. Just adding code here for the same.
`Time Complexity : O(n)` n - number of elements of array

```
package main.java;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {
   public static int solve(int[] a, int k) {
        int ans = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        MaxSlidingWindow maxSlidingWindow = new MaxSlidingWindow(k);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            ans = maxSlidingWindow.getMax() + a[i];
            maxSlidingWindow.add(i, ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {-9, -11, -10, 5, 20};
        System.out.print(Main.solve(input, 2));
    }
}

// at any point MaxSlidingWindow will have atmost k nodes
// with 'index' and 'val' monotonically decreasing from head to tail

class MaxSlidingWindow {
    int k;
    Deque<Node> q;

    class Node {
        int index;
        int val;
        Node(int index, int val) {
            this.index = index;
            this.val = val;
        }
    }

    MaxSlidingWindow(int k) {
        this.k = k;
        this.q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    public void add(int index, int val) {
        if (q.isEmpty()) {
            q.addLast(new Node(index, val));
        } else {
            if (index - q.peekFirst().index + 1 > k) {
                q.pollFirst(); // removing head as it is out of range
            }
            while (!q.isEmpty() && q.peekLast().val <= val) {
                q.pollLast(); // removing values in last less than current
            }
            q.addLast(new Node(index, val));
        }
    }
    public int getMax() {
        if (q.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return q.peekFirst().val;
    }
}
```